# TreeView, TreeNode, DirectoryInfo, C# - Хелп плиз)

Tags: c#

```
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

foreach (DriveInfo i in allDrives)
{
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(i.Name);
}

String path = treeView1.Nodes[0].Text;

DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
```

Я сделала такие махинации теперь у меня в Treeview выводит список дисков, теперь мне нужно положить в treeview1.Nodes[0].Nodes список файлов находящийся в dirs
То есть сделать дерево из файлов, в общем как в проводнике (если я хреново объяснила)

Comment: да и в чем проблема? `Directory.GetFiles(..)` ?

Comment: "Я сделала такие махинации" - Вы хотели сказать "манипуляции"?

Comment: Не знаю как это сделать

Comment: Как узлы в дерево добавлять вы знаете, как файлы из папки получить я вам показал. У вас все есть

Comment: Вас спасёт рекурсия. Напишите рекурсивную функцию, которая выводит в дерево список каталогов, затем вызывает саму себя для каждого из каталогов, а следующим циклом список файлов. В качестве аргумента функции используйте текущую ноду дерева, и изначально передайте ей корневую.

Comment: В этом [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OwyNiLPDNw)  автор делает похожее приложение.